# Using AppCompatDialog Removes titles from the Dialog

Tags: android, styles, android-appcompat, appcompatdialog

Once I switched from `ActionBarActivity` to `AppCompatActivity` one of the only changes I did was add this line:

```
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Here is my entire `styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="gptheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeNoActionBar" parent="gptheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Now, all the new `AppCompatDialog`s in my code, (which were formerly `Dialog d = new Dialog(mContext)`, all have no titles even though I use `setTitle()`.

Obviously the change I made to the titles specified `windowNoTitle` but that should only affect the parent activity.  I would think, anyway.

How exactly does this new feature work?

Comment: set parent style to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionbar and remove <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> attribute.

Comment: @Harry  That does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

// style.xml

```
<style name="DialogActivity" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#fff</item>
</style>
```

// manifest.xml

```
<activity
  android:name=".MyPopupActivity"
  android:theme="@style/DialogActivity"/>
```

// activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
public class MyPopupActivity extends Activity
{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_popup);
  }
}
```